# Need WooCommerce to force a specific product to be the only one in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've seen similar posts with functions.php solutions but none are exactly what I need.

I need my customers to sign up for membership by purchasing a zero cost product which creates their account and assigns a user role.

However, they must checkout with the membership product first and so this product must be the only one in cart when added. If other products are already there, cart should be emptied first. When this specific product is in the cart, no other products can be added and an "error" message must tell customers of this.

Is it possible to do this with a function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest going to a place like https://www.upwork.com/ if you need custom things developed. Stockoverflow is not a free workplace. Try writing php code yourself.

Comment: look into the woocommerce_before_cart action.

You can get into the cart details, modify cart items, throw woocommerce notices of type error, and a lot of other things.

I have done a similar thing like you want for a client (only allowing one category of products in the cart at a time).